# C - getaddrinfo returns "Servname not supported for ai_socktype"

Tags: c, sockets, udp, getaddrinfo

So, after I got this error, I've been looking for an answer in here, almost everyone had a difficult way to fix this error but no one explained why this error occurs at all, so I don't find this question to be exactly duplicate.

I wrote a TCP socket in C and I used "getaddrinfo" function to make the socket work with hostnames, well it worked perfectly! you can find my codes on [github](https://github.com/proph8/Sockets/tree/master/TCPEcho).

but when I tried to create a [UDP socket](https://github.com/proph8/Sockets/tree/master/UDPEcho) by "getaddrinfo" I got this error:
**Servname not supported for ai_socktype**

*client.c*

```
const char *host = argv[1];
const char *service = argv[2];
const char *string = argv[3];

struct addrinfo addrCriteria;
memset(&addrCriteria, 0, sizeof(addrCriteria));
addrCriteria.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
addrCriteria.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
addrCriteria.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_UDP;

struct addrinfo *servAddr;
int ret = getaddrinfo(host, service, &addrCriteria, &servAddr);
if(ret != 0)
    sysError(gai_strerror(ret));
```

I realized that when I give "service" a numeric input like 8080, no errors would return but when I use a string as service name like "tproxy" which points to port/8081, 'gai_strerror' returns mentioned error.

Obviously, gai_strerror says: "service names not supported for 'SOCK_DGRAM' socket types", but why? I mean the exact reason for "getaddrinfo" not supporting name services over UDP sockets?
Is there any other way to use service names with UDP sockets instead of port numbers? how?

Comment: I understand the answers as regarding a named service, but what's the answer when using AI_PASSIVE | AI_ADDRCONFIG, AF_INET6, and a numeric port with a null host? I expected a successful result I could then feed to bind, but got the "Servname not supported for ai_socktype error" anyhow. (port was 5454)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TL;DR: There is no `tproxy` UDP port.

---

If you look up the `tproxy` service for UDP sockets in your service database,

```
getent services tproxy/udp
```

You get no output, because `tproxy` is not an UDP service. If you look at all `tproxy` services regardless of the protocol, `getent services | grep -e tproxy`, you'll see

```
tproxy    8081/tcp
```

which means that `tproxy` service is only defined for TCP protocol.

This means that if you ask [`getaddrinfo()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html) for an UDP socket for service `8081`, you will not find anything, because `tproxy` is only defined for TCP and not UDP.

Compare to the case where you ask for and UDP socket for `xmpp-client` service. At least my service database (`getent services xmpp-client/udp`) responds with

```
xmpp-client           5222/udp jabber-client
```

and indeed, `getaddrinfo()` happily provides the socket description for such UDP sockets (using `xmpp-client` or `jabber-client` as the service).

So, there are services like `xmpp-client` that do have both TCP and UDP ports defined. On my system, `getent services | grep -e xmpp-client` shows

```
xmpp-client           5222/tcp jabber-client
xmpp-client           5222/udp jabber-client
```

Because TCP and UDP are different protocols over IP, it makes sense that a service could use a different port number for TCP and UDP communications. So, it is unreasonable to assume that the service database should just return the same port numbers for TCP and UDP sockets.

In other words, you encounter the error because you mistakenly assume that because some service uses a TCP port, with a name registered in the service database, you should be able to use that name to specify an UDP port number, too.

TCP and UDP are separate protocols, and their port number spaces are separate. For example, TCP port 512 is used by the Unix `exec` r-service, whereas UDP port 512 is used by the `biff` mail notification service.

Comment: I can't believe I missed '/etc/services' file and different service names for TCP and UDP! this was a great reminder of my major mistakes. it works with 'http-alt' servname as it was defined for both TCP and UDP connections. yep thank you for your great explanation!

Answer (score 3):

When a non-numeric value is given for the `service` parameter, it is looked up (on Linux) in the /etc/services file.  This file maps a service name to a port/protocol.  Below are some sample entries:

```
ssh             22/tcp  
telnet          23/tcp
domain          53/tcp                          # name-domain server
domain          53/udp
```

The reason you're getting an error is because there is no UDP entry in your /etc/services file for "tproxy".  Take a look at this file and look for an entry that does specify a UDP port such as "domain".  That should have entries for both 53/tcp and 53/udp.  If you pass in "domain" as the service name you should get a result back.